# Adicionar CSS em página específica via JS

Tags: javascript, css, blogger

Estou usando o Blogger atualmente, e quero adicionar estilos css a apenas uma página em específico. Já usei a uns tempos atrás um código padrão do próprio blogger que permitia isso (), mas ele não funciona mais. Então queria pedir a vocês que me dessem uma solução em JS que funcione da mesma forma. Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Qual é o CSS que queres adicionar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var FILE = '/assets/css/meucss.css';

var css = document.createElement('link');
css.setAttribute('rel','stylesheet');
css.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
css.setAttribute('href', FILE);

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css);
```

---

Se já tiver um `link` e só precisar alterar a referência, pode fazer assim no html:

```html
<!-- sem 'href' definido -->
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' id='dinamico'/>
```

E no Javascript pegá-lo pelo atributo id:

```
var FILE = 'meucss.css';
document.getElementById('dinamico').setAttribute('href', FILE);
```

---

No mais, dependendo de como estiver fazendo, pode usar um único arquivo css e utilizar classes no `body` para definir quais regras devem ser aplicadas naquele documento. Por exemplo:

```css
/**
 * O 'body' de todas as páginas que incluirem esse css será preto.
 */

body { background-color: black }


/**
 * O 'body' das páginas que incluirem a classe 'espefico' será azul.
 */
body.especifico { background-color: skyblue }
```

```html
<body class='especifico'>
  Qual a minha cor?
</body>
```