# Como carregar um arquivo CSS dinamicamente em jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, apache-cordova, aplicação-web

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação mobile em `HTML`, `JavaScript` e `CSS` utilizando o `phonegap`. Preciso ajustar / adequar o mesmo layout de uma página tanto para modo `portrait` quanto para modo `landscape`. Minha dúvida é a seguinte, quando eu identifica a mudança de modo, de `landscape` para `portrait` e vice-versa, eu quero carregar um `CSS` diferente, como faço para carregar um `CSS` dinamicamente em uma página utilizando `jQuery`?

Comment: [Não precisa JQuery](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94490/4808).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Se em jQuery não for possível, e em JavaScript como faço?

`jQuery` é um framework `javascript`. O intuito dele é tornar mais simples o que pode ser feito em `javascript`. Se é possível em `jQuery` então é possível em `javascript`.

> como faço para carregar um CSS dinamicamente em uma página utilizando **jQuery**

Você não precisa necessariamente do `jQuery` para fazer isso. Vou te mostrar uma forma de fazer utilizando `javascript` puro, e, caso você tenha interesse, você pode providenciar a migração para o `jQuery`.

Pro seu algoritmo vamos precisar basicamente de 2 passos:

1. verificar quando estamos em modo portrait ou landscape
2. alterar o atributo `href` de uma tag `link` para carregar o estilo adequado

---

## Verificando o modo

Você pode verificar o modo atual utilizando o seguinte código:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) {
    // MODO PORTRAIT
}

if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches) {
    // MODO LANDSCAPE
}
```

Você também pode criar uma função que verifica o tamanho da janela, caso queira alterar o estilo de acordo com uma determinada largura. Desse jeito você pode criar um estilo para dispositivos pequenos, médios, grandes, extra grandes. É exatamente isso que o [`bootstrap`](https://getbootstrap.com/) faz, no entanto isso é feito através de [`Media Queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries) e não `javascript`.

---

## Alterando o href

Essa parte é relativamente simples, você pode criar uma tag `link` com um id qualquer e modificar o atributo `href` de acordo com a condição que quiser. Segue um exemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="dynamic-link">

<script>
var dynamicLink = document.querySelector('#dynamic-link');

if (CONDICAO DO MODO PORTRAIT) {
    dynamicLink.setAttribute('href', 'portrait.css');
} else {
    dynamicLink.setAttribute('href', 'landscape.css');
}
</script>
```

---

## Media Queries

Ao invés de carregar arquivos dinamicamente, você tem a opção de criar um arquivo CSS único com algumas condições específicas, como declarações que são aplicadas apenas em determinados modos ou resoluções. Segue um exemplo:

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {  
    // ESTILO PARA MODO PORTRAIT    
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {     
    // ESTILO PARA MODO LANDSCAPE   
}
```

Segue o link da [`especificação de Media Queries`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation) para maiores informações.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Romulo!